# Unable to update model with virtual list

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

My movie model has a virtual declaration of ICollection which is working fine in all cases except one. When I try to edit the list from a session variable and call _db.SaveChanges, it is not getting updated to db. Let me tell that I also have a ProducerId field (along with virtual Producer) which is getting updated properly. Where is it going wrong?

Movie model - Movie.cs

```
public class Movie
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int MovieId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string YearOfRelease { get; set; }
    public string Plot { get; set; }
    public string ImgUrl { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Producer")]
    public int ProducerId { get; set; }

    public virtual Producer Producer { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Actor> Actors { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<MovieReview> Reviews { get; set; }

}
```

CreateOrEdit Controller -

```
public ActionResult CreateOrEdit([Bind(Include = "MovieId, Name, Plot, YearOfRelease")]Movie movie)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            int session_producerId = (int)Session["ProducerId"];
            movie.Producer = _db.Producers.Find(session_producerId);
            movie.ProducerId = session_producerId;

            List<int> actors = Session["Actors"] as List<int>;
            ICollection<Actor> session_actors = _db.Actors.Where(a => actors.Contains(a.ActorId)).ToList<Actor>(); 
            movie.Actors = session_actors;

            // add the movie to db before saving if creating new
            if (movie.MovieId == 0)
                _db.Movies.Add(movie);
            else
            // else trigger the edits 
                _db.Entry(movie).State = EntityState.Modified;

            // finally save changes
            _db.SaveChanges();

            // removing session information
            Session.Clear();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(movie);
    }
```

Can someone help me to understand why does _db.Entry(movie).State = EntityState.Modified not updating the Actors collection? Any kind of help is appreciated.

Comment: I am not deleting the actors from actors list. Please read the question properly.

Comment: Actually you mentioned about removing actor from actors set, so that confused me as I am assigning actors to movie object. Coming to your answer, may I know why EF treats collections differently? Also, do I need to manually "delete and add" actors to movie collection or is there any simpler way?

Comment: check my answer on [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24176625/entity-framework-how-to-merge-child-collections-best-practices/24177980#24177980)

Comment: Shouldn't virtual keyword be responsible for assigning? Else, it looks like a lot of work if there were too many collections to update. I am still looking for an intuitive answer.

Comment: I tried how you mentioned, still not working for me. Can you tell me what is the solution specific to my case here and why is mine not working.

Comment: Ok, I'll try to get the right code for you..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
    Movie movieDb;
    if (movie.MovieId == 0)
    {
        movieDb = new Movie { Actors = new List<Actor>() };
        _db.Movies.Add(movieDb);
    }
    else
    {
        movieDb = _db.Movies.Include(m => m.Actors).FirstOrDefault(m => m.MovieId == movie.MovieId);
    }

    // Sets producer.
    int session_producerId = (int)Session["ProducerId"];
    movieDb.Producer = _db.Producers.Find(session_producerId);
    movieDb.ProducerId = session_producerId;

    // Sets actors.
    List<int> actors = Session["Actors"] as List<int>;
    ICollection<Actor> session_actors = _db.Actors.Where(a => actors.Contains(a.ActorId)).ToList<Actor>();
    Array.ForEach(session_actors.ToArray(), actor => movieDb.Actors.Add(actor));

    // Sets other movie's properties here..


    // finally save changes
    _db.SaveChanges();

    // removing session information
    Session.Clear();
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Comment: So, we need to 'Include' the virtual collection to let EF do the change tracking. Thanks a lot for spending time and providng accurate answer!